# c# add Regex pattern dynamically from remote XML file

Tags: c#, regex, xml

My regex patterns are stored remote in a XML file.
I want to add them dynamically at runtime to my appliction.

The related code is the following:

```
//count length of rules
countRules = regexFile.DocumentElement.SelectNodes("/regex/item/rule").Count;
ruleIndex = 0;
//array of pattern objects
pattern = new Regex[countRules];
//allocate regex rules
foreach (XmlNode node in regexFile.DocumentElement.SelectNodes("/regex/item"))
            {
                string rule = node["rule"].InnerText;
                string text = rule;

                pattern[ruleIndex] = new Regex(text);

                //deny increment after last item
                if (ruleIndex < (countRules-1))
                {
                    ruleIndex++;
                }
            }
```

The XML file has entries like this:

```
<item>
    <rule>\\b[A-ZÄÖÜ]{1}\\d{6}\\b</rule>
</item>
```

Also tried with quotes:

```
<item>
    <rule>"\\b[A-ZÄÖÜ]{1}\\d{6}\\b"</rule>
</item>
```

After logging and dubugging I am pretty sure it is the following line:

```
pattern[ruleIndex] = new Regex(text);
```

When i do the static variante it works:

```
pattern[ruleIndex] = new Regex("\\b[A-ZÄÖÜ]{1}\\d{6}\\b");
```

Do I set the parameter wrong for new Regex("")? It should have quotes?

Comment: What's the problem?

Comment: Insert the XML value to new Regex(text) does not work.

Comment: \\ in a string is a [escape sequence](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-language/escape-sequences?view=vs-2017). Put `\b[A-ZÄÖÜ]{1}\d{6}\b` in your xaml

Comment: Oh dear, indeed the double backslash was the mistake, thanks a lot Christian. You can do this as answer if you like.

Comment: Wasnt there a version with one backslash before?

Comment: No need, I'm just glad it helped.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just tested your snippet and the regex itself seems to work.

I assume yor XML looks like the following (only one backslash)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<regex>
  <item>
    <rule>\b[A-ZÄÖÜ]{1}\d{6}\b</rule>
  </item>
</regex>
```

and there is only one rule in each item. Otherwise you won't load them all, with your approach.

You could however be much shorter:

```
var pattern = new List<Regex>();
foreach (XmlNode node in regexFile.DocumentElement.SelectNodes("/regex/item/rule"))
{
  pattern.Add(new Regex(node.InnerText));
}
```

Comment: Correct answer as Christian above said the backslash. BTW I can add several rules into my patter array. Just have to add the rule as XML item. That works I just tested.

Comment: If you would have added more than one ruler per item, it would not have worked. In the worst case, it would not even crash, but just not have taken all rules. Because the node["rule"] can only give back one rule per item.
This way you can have many rules per item, which would have been counted before, but not imported.